# alternative of curl_setopt in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code which replaces the remove image using curl it works without issue but I want to use wordpress native function to accomplish this.

```
function image( $destination_path, $remote_image_link ) {
    $ch =  curl_init( $remote_image_link );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );

    if ( $result ) {
        $rv = file_put_contents( $destination_path, $result );
    }
}
```

Want to achieve same with `wp_remote` or some other function .Any help will be great

Comment: `wp_remote_get`?

Comment: @smoqadam yes how to use that one  here

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get

Comment: @smoqadam i am not getting how to use for above function

Comment: Replace the 3 curl lines with `$result = wp_remote_get($remote_image_link);`

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: @WahyuKristianto done. thx for guiding

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very simple.

wp_remote_get output is big array and in that array body contains the main details as here i have only one link just need to do

```
$result = wp_remote_get($remote_image_link['body']);
```

Hope it helps someone as wp documentation is not clear